# Error trapping in SFTP

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Im trying to write a unix script that would push file into another server.
I need to know if the file was successfully pushed.

So far what I've found is to write the sftp error into a file.

```
sftp ${SFTP_USER}@${SFTP_HOST} << ENDP 2> /var/local/err_log.txt
cd ${SFTP_DIR}
put ${OUTPUT_FILE}
bye
ENDP
```

My assumption is that "2>" would only write the error in the err_log.
So if my err_log is not empty, it means I have encountered an error.

My question is, is this a good approach? 
is it correct assumption that only error would be written in the err_log file?
Are there other better ways to do this?

Comment: `if rsync -ua /file/to/transfer ${user}@${host}:/path/to/put/it ; then echo "all good"; else echo "xfer failed"; fi` seems like a whole lot better way to approach it. (presumes `ssh` access available on `host`)

Comment: hi David, ssh access isn't available. only sftp was provided.

Comment: Bummer -- `rsync` is so much more capable...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restrict *stderr* logging to *errors*-only, you should use the `Quiet`mode:

```
   -q     Quiet mode: disables the progress meter as well as  warning  and
          diagnostic messages from ssh(1).
```

Comment: quite mode is for scp? unfortunately only sftp access was provided to me.

Comment: I use openssh 7.2. *Quiet mode* Is available here in the *sftp* command